# How to install R studio on xfce remote desktop?

Tags: 18.04, xfce, r, rstudio, x11rdp

I am currently handling my remote server through RDP with an Xfce desktop interface. It has an ubuntu 18.04 version. I want to use it for implementing R and I am quite familiar with R-Studio. Can I somehow install it through the Xfce GUI interface? If yes, how? If not, what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to open Xfce terminal and then execute the following commands to install R and RStudio:

```
sudo apt-get update

cd ~/Downloads
wget -c https://rstudio.org/download/latest/stable/desktop/bionic/rstudio-latest-amd64.deb -O rstudio-latest-amd64.deb \

# build deps for many R-packages
sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libxml2-dev libcairo2-dev

# RStudio by itself
sudo apt-get install ./rstudio-latest-amd64.deb
```

Then run `rstudio` from terminal or find RStudio in Xfce menu.

Comment: It seems that it has been installed. Where can I access it?

Comment: Run `rstudio` from terminal or find it in Xfce menu.